# Sparktables: How can I output addition table elements?

Tags: r, sparktable

I have a data frame (Counts of faults in MS Office over a number of years)  which I am using to generate a sparktable successfully:

```
df_Office_final_sparktable
component   faults time
Excel       2      2001
Excel       1      2002
Excel       5      2003
Excel       5      2004
Excel       5      2005
Excel       6      2006
Excel       0      2007
Excel       0      2008
Excel       0      2009
Excel       0      2010
Excel       0      2011
Excel       0      2012
PPT         1      2001
PPT         1      2002
PPT         1      2003
PPT         1      2004
PPT         2      2005
PPT         3      2006
PPT         0      2007
PPT         0      2008
PPT         0      2009
PPT         0      2010
PPT         0      2011
PPT         0      2012
Word        5      2001
Word        4      2002
Word        3      2003
Word        1      2004
Word        3      2005
Word        2      2006
Word        5      2007
Word        3      2008
Word        0      2009
Word        1      2010
Word        0      2011
Word        0      2012
```

Here is the corresponding code:

`Office_content<-list(`

```
2001=function(x) { head(x,1) },
2012=function(x) { tail(x,1) },
Office_content[['Office Trend']]<-newSparkLine())
Office_varType<-rep("outages",3)  df_Office_final_sparktable<-df_Office_final_sparktable[,c("component","faults","time")]  df_Office_final_sparktable$time<-as.numeric(as.character(df_Office_final_sparktable$time))     Office_dat<-reshapeExt(df_Office_final_sparktable,idvar="component",varying=list(2))
Office_sparkTab<-newSparkTable(Office_dat,Office_content,Office_varType)
showSparkTable (Office_sparkTab , outputType = "html", filename = "t1")
```

As you can see I am able to output a table of the 2001 and 2012 faults using the head commands and a corresponding sparkline. However I can't seem to figure out how to output the fault totals from 2002 - 2011 (inclusive) I tried to pull the second row from of the dataframe using the following code:

```
df_Office_final_sparktable[2:2, 1:3]
```

I realise this isn't correct as there is no way for me to map this command back to a function so i was wondering do i need to write 10 separate functions that i need to call in order to pull the required fault totals for each office component year on year?

Thanks in advance, 
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally figured this one out. I had to create 10 functions which would pull the 2nd row from the data frame like so:

```
head_row2_Office <- function(x) {
result <- subset(x, time =='2002' & component =="Excel", select=c(1:3))
return (result)
}
```

After that i had to call the functions in the list function like so:

```
Office_content<-list(
Jan=function(x) { head(x,1) },
Feb=function(x) { head_row2_Office(x) },
Mar=function(x) { head_row3_Office(x) },
Apr=function(x) { head_row4_Office(x) },
May=function(x) { head_row5_Office(x) },
Jun=function(x) { head_row6_Office(x) },
Jul=function(x) { head_row7_Office(x) },
Aug=function(x) { head_row8_Office(x) },
Sep=function(x) { head_row9_Office(x) },
Oct=function(x) { head_row10_Office(x) },
Nov=function(x) { head_row11_Office(x) },
Dec=function(x) { tail(x,1) },
Office_content[['Office Trend']]<-newSparkLine()
)

Office_varType<-rep("outages",13) # set the tables columns to 13 for table + graph
df_Office_final_sparktable<-df_Office_final_sparktable[,c("component","faults","time")]
df_Office_final_sparktable$time<-as.numeric(as.character(df_Office_final_sparktable$time))
Office_dat<-reshapeExt(df_Office_final_sparktable,idvar="component",varying=list(2))
Office_sparkTab<-newSparkTable(Office_dat,Office_content,Office_varType)
showSparkTable (Office_sparkTab , outputType = "html", filename = "t1")
```